# How to open sales orders list view by context menu button in odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I want to open sales orders list view for any customer when click on context button. For this i getting all the ids on terminal but not getting list view. So, How to open customer sales orders list(Sales). For this my code is below.

**Python Code:**

```
sale_order_count = fields.Integer(compute='_compute_sale_order_count', string='# of Sales Order')

    def _compute_sale_order_count(self):

            ir_model_data = self.env['ir.model.data']

            try:

                view_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('sale', 'view_order_tree')[1]

            except ValueError:

                view_id = False

            record_id = self.env['sale.order'].search([('partner_id', '=', self.ren9.id)]).ids

            print "viewssss:::", view_id, record_id

            if not record_id:

                print "Not found"

            else:

                print "return,,", record_id[0]

                return {

                    'view_type': 'tree',

                    'view_mode': 'tree',

                    'views': [(view_id, 'tree')],

                    'res_model': 'sale.order',

                    'view_id': view_id,

                    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',

                    'res_id': record_id,

                    'target': 'new',

                }
```

**XML Code:**

```
 <div name="button_box" position="inside">

                        <button class="oe_stat_button" type="action" name="_compute_sale_order_count"

                                icon="fa-usd">

                            <field string="Sales" name="sale_order_count" widget="statinfo"/>

                        </button>

                    </div>
```

**For 4 sales orders print on terminal:**

viewssss::: 506 [101, 100, 99, 98]

return,, 101

Thanks in advance,

Comment: but `view_id` is not null it's `506`  and change `'view_type': 'form',` it's better to use form type even when you show record in tree view.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the follwing

**Python code:**

```
     def _view_sale_orders(self):
        ir_model_data = self.env['ir.model.data']
        try:
           tree_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('sale', 'view_order_tree').id
           form_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference('sale', 'view_order_form').id
        except ValueError:
            view_id = False

        partner_id = self.ren9.id
        return {
            'name': _('Sale Orders'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'domain': [('partner_id', '=', partner_id)],
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'res_model': 'sale.order',
            'view_id': False,
            'views': [(tree_id, 'tree'),(form_id, 'form')],
            'target': 'current',
            'context': ctx,
        }
```

**XML Code:**

```
 <div name="button_box" position="inside">

       <button class="oe_stat_button" type="object" name="_view_sale_orders" icon="fa-usd">

        <field string="Sales" name="sale_order_count" widget="statinfo"/>

     </button>

   </div>
```